# Are there any other differences between bitcoin and bitcoin cash

Tags: bitcoin-cash

Bitcoin Cash was forked from a Bitcoin almost 2 months ago. During this time both of the repos have received a lot of commits and I would assume that their functionality and features might have diverged.

But it looks like a lot of resources mentioning the difference between BTC and BCH are either telling how amazing BCH is or how crappy it is. The maximum they tell is that the difference is that BCH removes all the changes related to SegWit and increases MaxBlockSize to 8Mb.

Another difference that I was able to find is that BCH added emergency difficulty adjustment: if less than 6 blocks were created in 12 hours, the difficulty drops by 20%.

---

Basically my question boils down to: what are the technical differences between bitcoin and bitcoin cash as of Sep 20, 2017?

Comment: Are you talking about differences between Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash (the consensus and protocol rules of the networks), or about differences between Bitcoin Core and Bitcoin-ABC (software projects that implement the respective protocols). Changes to the software almost never related to protocol changes.

Comment: @PieterWuille mostly about software changes. Because I assume that they will also include protocol changes.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no protocol changes occurred in either since august 1st (apart from SegWit activating on Bitcoin, using code that had been in Core for over a year at that point). At least in Bitcoin, protocol changes are rare and slow.

Comment: Search for `SIGHASH_FORKID`